# Почему иконка появляется только на 1 изображении?

Tags: css, icon

```css
.gallery {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.gallery img {
 
 float: left;
}
.container {
 position: relative;
}
.container span {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 140px;
 top: 125px;
 color: white;
}
.container:hover  .dropdown{
 
 display: block;
}
.container:hover img {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
 <div class="gallery">
   <div class="container">
    <img src="" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown">
    </span>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <img src="" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown">
    </span>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <img src="" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown">
    </span>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <img src="" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown">
    </span>
   </div>
   
  </div>
```

Comment: А где собственно иконка?

Comment: на первый взгляд без проверки ...  вас для img есть float хотя по идее надо смещать container именно его , именно он у вас родитель для внутренних элементов ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я заменил имя вашего class : container на items и иконку на span внутри которого знак : плюс

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.items {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.items span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}

.items:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.items img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <span>+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <span>+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <span>+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <span>+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <span>+</span>
  </div>
</div>
```